Presigned URL with filename using AWS SDK CPP
I managed to generate a presigned url to download a S3 file with AWS SDK CPP:
std::string presigned_url = s3_client.GeneratePresignedUrl(bucket, key, Aws::Http::HttpMethod::HTTP_GET, EXPIRATION_TIME);

How can I get the presigned url with an attached filename format as 'response-content-disposition'?

Perhaps the overloaded GeneratePresignedUrl variant that supports a parameter for const Http::HeaderValueCollection& customizedHeaders.

@jarmod I tried, but I couldn't find a way to make it work.
